# Switch page with onsen navigator and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Is there any way to switch page, using ons-navigator without ons-template tag?
For example, i have project like this:

```
--app.js
--index.html
--page1.html
```

When i describe page1.html into index.html, using ons-template (like this http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/yrhtv) everything is going OK. But if i'am trying to set path into

```
myNavigator.pushPage('page1.html', { animation : 'slide' } )
```

without using ons-template my app doesn't work.

Comment: Are you serving the app with a web server or are you just opening the file with your browser?

You need to use a web server since Onsen will make a request to fetch `page1.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ons-template>` without `<ons-navigator>` but not the other way around. Navigator object is something like Angular routing system and it needs templates in order to send data between pages.